# Comparing a string and integer (java)

Tags: java, string, parsing, int, compare

I'm having trouble with some Java programming and I'm pretty confused on how the comparison operands work between inputs.

What I want is for my program to take input, analyze the input, check what it's equal to, and display a message based upon their input. How am I to compare the input, to the `option1` variable I have set?

Here's one file, called ***loadfile.java***

```
package subsets;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class loadfile {

        public static void main(String args[]) {

        }

        public static void choose(String[] args) {

            // Set an option
            int option1 = 1;

            // Start grabbing input
            System.out.print("Choose one: ");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );
            String input = scanner.nextLine();

            // Parse input into an integer (expecting int)
            int selection = Integer.parseInt(input);

            // If input == option1, let's go with this code.
            if(input.equals(option1)){

                System.out.println("You choose option 1.");

            }
        }
}
```

I have `loadfile.choose(args);` in a different file, and that file handles the rest of the files I will be implementing.

Here's the file: ***otherfile.java***

```
package subsets;

public class otherfile {

        public static void main(String args[]){
            System.out.println("Please select an option (using number keys): \n");
            System.out.println(
                    "1. Option 1 \n"
                    + "2. Option 2 \n"
                    + "3. Option 3 \n"
                    + "4. option 4 \n");

            // Start analyzing their choice
            loadfile.choose(args);
        }

}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why can't I compare the input to the option variable I have set? (sorry, I meant to imply this).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: I'm not asking to how to compare strings..

Comment: Well, seemingly you should be doing `if (selection == option1)` because right now you parse the input to an `int`, but do not do anything with it.

Comment: Or, you could be declaring option1 as a String, since you know you're going to be doing a comparison with another String value later on. You also know you're not doing any calculations with option1, so the fact that it's a numeral is strictly cosmetic. I hate to say, but you seem to have tunnel-visioned your way into a corner for no real reason.

Comment: Whether you compare as a string or a number matters. `10` > `9` but `"10" < "9"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either change your `int option1 = 1;` to `String option1 = "1";` or parse the user input as integer or do `scanner.nextInt()` instead of `nextLine` there are lots of options to fix this here. `Integer.parseInt(String)`.

Comment: Thanks, let me try a few.

Comment: Thanks, @brso05, worked like a charm.

Comment: @LoganButler your welcome glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

`equals()` is only valid between objects of the same type.

`int` is not even an object, but Java converts it implicitly to an `Integer` object when it passes it as the parameter to a method that expects an `Object` (an `Integer` is an `Object` - all classes extend `Object`).

But now `equals` is left with comparing a `String` object to an `Integer` object. Since they are not of the same type, this will always be false.

To do the comparison properly, you have to get an integer from the string by *parsing* it into an `int`. For example, using `Integer.parseInt()`.

And... you did exactly that, but you forgot to use the result of your operation. You have the `selection` variable, simply compare `selection` instead of `input`.

Of course, in this case you'll simply use `selection == option1` instead of using `equals`, because `int` is primitive and doesn't have methods.

Answer (score 0):

In general the `equals` method does **not** return true when comparing objects of different types. This is the implementation of `String#equals(Object)`:

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
   if (this == anObject) {
       return true;
   }
   if (anObject instanceof String) {
       String anotherString = (String)anObject;
       int n = count;
       if (n == anotherString.count) {
          char v1[] = value;
          char v2[] = anotherString.value;
          int i = offset;
          int j = anotherString.offset;
          while (n-- != 0) {
              if (v1[i++] != v2[j++])
              return false;
          }
          return true;
       }
   }
   return false;
}
```

Note the check `if (anObject instanceof String)`.

In your case, I don't see why not simply doing:

```
if (selection == option1) {
```

since you already got the `selection` variable.